# How to register a custom ProtocolMapper in Keycloak?

Tags: keycloak

I'm struggling with registering a custom ProtocolMapper in Keycloak. I would like to add some data from my database on token request. So i followed the idea given in [Keycloak add extra claims from database / external source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43376233/keycloak-add-extra-claims-from-database-external-source).

I implemented the ProtocolMapper interface and added the file

> META-INF/services/org.keycloak.protocol.ProtocolMapper

containing the reference to my class. So far so good and Keycloak recognizes the new implementation. I'm also able to configure it via the admin console.

To add some data to the token I think I must also add one/some of the interfaces

> org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.mappers.UserInfoTokenMapper
>   org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.mappers.OIDCIDTokenMapper
>   org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.mappers.OIDCAccessTokenMapper

and implement the methods according to the interface(s).

The problem now is that as soon as I add the interface I get the following log message:

```
08:55:07,292 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."keycloak-spi.jar".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."keycloak-spi.jar".POST_MODULE
: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "keycloak-spi.jar"
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:172)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2032)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1955)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link at/lotterien/jam/keycloak/spi/JamAuthorizationInfoProtocolMapper (Module "deployment.keycloak-spi.jar" from Service Module Loader): org/keycloak/protocol/oidc/mappers/UserInfoTokenMapper
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:446)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:274)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:77)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:713)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:412)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:400)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(Unknown Source)
        at org.keycloak.provider.DefaultProviderLoader.load(DefaultProviderLoader.java:60)
        at org.keycloak.provider.ProviderManager.load(ProviderManager.java:92)
        at org.keycloak.services.DefaultKeycloakSessionFactory.loadFactories(DefaultKeycloakSessionFactory.java:214)
        at org.keycloak.services.DefaultKeycloakSessionFactory.deploy(DefaultKeycloakSessionFactory.java:115)
        at org.keycloak.provider.ProviderManagerRegistry.deploy(ProviderManagerRegistry.java:42)
        at org.keycloak.subsystem.server.extension.KeycloakProviderDeploymentProcessor.deploy(KeycloakProviderDeploymentProcessor.java:55)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:165)
        ... 5 more
```

Why does Keycloak not find its own interface? Shouldn't it be provided out of the box?

What do I miss to make it work?

---

**Edit 1**

I got a little bit further. I added a file

> META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml

with content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-services"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

and now the exception is gone.

Unfortunately the method *transformUserInfoToken()* in my class is still not called on token request.

Can anyone put me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It finally works. Even there are still open questions I could implement the needed functionality.

I had to implement the Interface

> org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.mappers.OIDCAccessTokenMapper

(instead of `org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.mappers.UserInfoTokenMapper`)

Now my *transformAccessToken()* method is called on every request to URL `http://<host>:<port>/auth/realms/testrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token`

I think the problem came from my misunderstanding of the terms AccessToken, UserInfo and IDToken. I thought all three are part of the token generated. But it seems the *OIDCAccessTokenMapper* is the only way to get additional information into the access token.

The remaining open question for me is where the UserInfo and the IDToken would appear. Maybe somebody can give an answer for that.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution.
Do you think you could provide a more detailed process to achieve this ?
To begin with how did you "implement the ProtocolMapper interface" you mention in your question ?
Also where did you add the file META-INF/services/org.keycloak.protocol.ProtocolMapper

I don't find this META-INF folder in the keycloak directory.

Thank you again for your post.

Comment: You have to create a new Java/Maven project with dependencies like _org.keycloak:keycloak-core_, _org.keycloak:keycloak-server-spi_ and _org.keycloak:keycloak-server-spi-private_. The META-INF folder would then have to be created in _src/main/resources/META-INF_. The file in _META_INF/keycloak-server-spi-private_ has to contain the full qualified name of the class that implements the _org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.mappers.OIDCAccessTokenMapper_ interface. Also have a look at the [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.3/server_development/topics/providers.html). I hope this helps.

Comment: @rbachlec do you happen to have a working code example publicly on github?  I have tried all the steps here, but keycloak still doesn't list my custom Protocol Mapper in the built-ins when I try to add it to one of my clients.

Comment: this example here (not mine) should be complete
https://github.com/mschwartau/keycloak-custom-protocol-mapper-example
To be precise the project in https://github.com/mschwartau/keycloak-custom-protocol-mapper-example/tree/master/protocol-mapper
It´s just missing the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` - he *solved* it by using a module and a `module.xml` instead of directly deploying ist

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for MY specific problem.

I had the same error - but already had a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` with comparable contents. The reason it didn't work for me was that I had an EAR containing my implementation and libs as JARs. So the needed structure for `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` differed.

I post it here for others struggling with the same problem:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.1">
    <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <system export="true">
                <paths>
                    <path name="com/sun/xml/internal/ws/spi"/>
                </paths>
            </system>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
    <sub-deployment name="org.my.implementation-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar">
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-core"/>
            <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi"/>
            <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private"/>
            <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-services"/>
            <module name="javax.ws.rs.api"/>
        </dependencies>
    </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```