# Modify roles in Keycloak Token after user login SPI

Tags: jwt, keycloak

I'm trying to add more roles into the token after the token has been generated following the isValid() return of the Authentication SPI.

I have a application which has SMS otp functionality. After the user has verified the OTP I want to grant more roles to the user by adding those roles into the token(edit: new generated token with new values as JWT cannot be modified). But how do I modify the token or the new generated token with new roles ?
Is there a endpoint I can use to do so ? Or anyother ProviderInterface that I can use to achieve this ?

Comment: A token can't be modified. Adding something to the token means to create a new token with the additional roles or claims.

Comment: Regenerating is not a problem as long as I'm able to add additional roles and attributes into the new token. Still couldn't find any solution to it. Any pointers please ?

Comment: I'm not using keycloak, but maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43376233/keycloak-add-extra-claims-from-database-external-source or search for "keycloak adding claims" and see what comes up.